# jQuery Hide Toggeled Div On Document.click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn_signIn').click(function(){
    $('#div_signInBox').toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

I need to hide the div_signInBox toggled div anytime any other part of the window is clicked...

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question? Can you please clarify?

Comment: To post code fragments, just paste in the raw code, select it all, and then click the `{}` widget at the top of the edit box.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$(function() {
    $('#div_signInBox,html').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is('#div_signInBox')) 
            return false;

        $('#div_signInBox').toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is close but now you can click anywhere on the screen and the div_signInBox appears...

Comment: Oh i read that you want to toggle the div anytime the window is clicked. Well if you just want to hide it change the toggle() to hide() or fadeOut() ...